# LAZY PROBLEMS handling objects of class $$enhancerbycglib

Tags: hibernate

I have a class Car and a Class Prenot ...

```
@Entity
@Table(name="car"
    ,catalog="gestcars")
public class Car implements java.io.Serializable {
     private String targ;
     private String model;
     private Set<Prenot> prenots = new HashSet<Prenot>(0);
    public Car() {
    }
…….}

public class Prenot  implements java.io.Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name="codice", unique=true, nullable=false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy =GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int codice;
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="car_targ", nullable=false)
     private Car car;
    …..}
```

The first call to this

```
For(x: …some cicle)…
     try {
            if(!session.isOpen()){
              this.session=util1.HibernateUtil1.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            }

        org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Criteria crit=session.createCriteria(Prenot.class);
        crit.add(Expression.eq("data", newdata))
        .addOrder(Order.asc("data"))
        .addOrder(Order.asc("from"));        
        prenot = (List<Prenot>) crit.list();
        session.flush();
        session.close();.....
return prenot;
```

returns to me and object Prenot, and it use a EAGER fetched,  in fact i can get an object Car whit the code

```
Iterator i = prenot.iterator();
                while (i.hasNext()) {
                    Prenot tempP = (Prenot) i.next();
                   Car c = tempP.getCar();…… }
```

The  ulterior iterqtion of the cicle (for x…) in the list prenot returned I have an object      Car$$enhancerbycglib$$...
Why?. I changed from lazy to eager because i can.’t handle the  $$enhancerbycglib$$ object. How i can?

it looks to change the type of object fetched after a this call :

```
   org.hibernate.Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();
       session.save(p);
        session.flush();
       tx.commit();
```

Comment: I really can't understand what is your question .

Comment: The problem is why the first query returns me an object and the other succesiive queries return me e proxy?